# Tabs on twitter-bootsrap not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am working with bootstrap tabs and jQuery, but its not working.

**Markup**

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">bmnmn,b,mbn...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">.werewr..</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">.jkhk..</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">llkjlk...</div>
</div>
```

**JS FILE**

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).tab('show');
})
```

[Here is the jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/w1zm8rqt/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert following line in your markup

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the `bootstrap.js` (or just the [tab.js-file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/tab.js)) that comes with Bootstrap? Your fiddle works fine with just the Bootstrap.js (even with older 2.0.2 that JsFiddle offers)

```
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Remember to include this after jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/8zz02ve0/

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I'm getting 
ReferenceError: $ is not defined on my sites.

Comment: I've added 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> @Pete TNT

Comment: Make sure that your scripts are included after jQuery and Bootstrap, so that the order from top to bottom would be 1. jQuery 2. Bootstrap, 3. Your own JavaScript file

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust your js to:

```
$('#myTab li').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myTab li').removeClass('active'); //remove active from all <li>
    $(this).addClass('active'); //add active class to <li> you clicked on
});
```

#### [Update Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w1zm8rqt/5/)